# Unable to run custom modules

Tags: linux, module

I am trying to create custom private environment modules on an HPC cluster as shown here: https://researchcomputing.princeton.edu/support/knowledge-base/custom-modules

My private modules appear in the output of the `module avail` command. However, when I try to load one of these, I get the following error:

```
Lmod has detected the following error: /home/a_thomas.iitr/modulefiles/qe_7.0: (qe_7.0): can't read "_sp_initializing:-": no such variable 
While processing the following module(s):
    Module fullname  Module Filename
    ---------------  ---------------
    qe_7.0           /home/a_thomas.iitr/modulefiles/qe_7.0
```

The contents of `qe_7.0` module are given below:

```
#%Module1.0

source /home/apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh
spack load hdf5@1.10.7%oneapi@2021.4.0
spack load intel-oneapi-compilers@2021.4.0%gcc@11.2.0

set QE_PATH /scratch/a_thomas.iitr/files_temp/SWs/7.0_install
prepend-path PATH $QE_PATH/bin
```

I scoured the internet for any information regarding this but to no avail.
Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage you linked says:

> Module files are written in the Tcl language.

This line seems to be trying to read a `.sh` shell script:

```
source /home/apps/spack/share/spack/setup-env.sh
```

In the Tcl language, [the `source` command expects the specified file to be another Tcl script](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/source.html), not a shell script.

If the `setup-env.sh` contains text like `_sp_initializing:-` (or something that becomes that when (mis)interpreted according to rules of Tcl), that would confirm the issue.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM  Yes, I check the .sh file, and it indeed contains an if statement with this text. Not sourcing this file has removed the error. However, this file needs to be sourced to use spack. Is there a way to source .sh files using module?

Comment: With a brief search, I could not find one - and based on how environment variables can be inherited from a parent process by a child process, but not passed in the reverse direction, I don't think it would be possible. You probably will have to translate the contents of the `setup-env.sh` into equivalent Tcl code.

Comment: You may use the `source-sh` modulefile command to source this sh script shell in the evaluation context of this modulefile: https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MIGRATING.html#source-sh-modulefile-command.
however the `spack load` commands will raise other errors, as spack is not a modulefile command.